# high charts pie chart should be displayed in ascending order

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I have a pie chart. I want the slices to ascending order of the value.
Like 50%,30%,10%...automatically. And it should begin to plot from 12 o clock on the circular pie.
Regards
Joseph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you would need to pre-process your data before making your `series.data`. The start angle is adjustable using [`startAngle`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.startAngle). It does start from the 12 o'clock position by default (`startAngle: 0`).